# Zustand: One State Split Into Slices or Multiple Stores?

Tags: reactjs, react-state, react-state-management, zustand, global-state

I'm using Zustand for state management. Currently, I have 20 slices. And I'm afraid the number of slices will triple. What would be the best approach, splitting one really large state into slices or creating multiple stores (and splitting each one of them into slices if needed)? What are the pros and cons of each approach for a large state?

Comment: hey did you find an answer yet? Looking for the best practice of that as well. Thanks